# Estimate the cost of an individual item in a mixed bag, knowing only the total value of the bag (multiple samples with different mixes allowed)

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Lets say I have a swimming pool filled with differently coloured balls. There are a fixed number of different colours. Each differently coloured ball has set cost (not necessarily unique) that I don't know.

I can take as many random samples of the pool as required (e.g. I can fill 1000 bags with 100 randomly sampled balls from the pool). I know the total cost of each bag and how many balls of each colour there are in each bag.

How can I determine the cost for each ball colour?

(Apologies in advance if I didn't put the correct tag, math newb here - corrections are most welcome)

Comment: won't you just have (in your example) 1000 equations with $k$ unknowns where $k$ is the number of different colors? If (and only if) you have $k$ linearly independent equations, you can solve them for the unknown costs of each color ball.

Comment: I think that's correct - thanks!